# Why isn't Formik group checkbox working if the initial state is loaded from a variable?

Tags: reactjs, forms, checkbox, formik, checkboxlist

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Formik, Field, Form } from "formik";

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));
const ALL_CELEBS = ["apples", "bananas", "oranges", "grapes"];
const CELEBS = ["apples", "grapes"];
const Basic = () => (
  <div>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        result: [],
      }}
      onSubmit={async (values) => {
        await sleep(500);
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      }}
    >
      {({ values }) => (
        <Form>
          <div role="group" aria-labelledby="checkbox-group">
            {ALL_CELEBS.map((celeb) => (
              <label key={celeb}>
                <Field
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="result"
                  value={celeb}
                  checked={CELEBS.includes(celeb)}
                />
                {celeb}
              </label>
            ))}
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Basic />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/floral-tdd-klyz33

If I remove `checked` attribute everything seems to work fine.
I have already read other question on stackoverflow to load checkbox initial state like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61352349/how-to-make-formik-detect-when-checkbox-field-is-checked), they don't seem to be answering for the group case.

Answer (score 0):

Check attribute will make it checked all the time not just the initial values,
So we need to remove checked attribute from `Field` tag, and add values  `initialValues`

`initialValues` to this:

```
initialValues={{
   result: CELEBS,
}}
```

and `Field` tag to this:

```
<Field
   type="checkbox"
   name="result"
   value={celeb}
/>
```

`CELEBS` is array ie `const CELEBS=["apples", "grapes"]`.

Having `name="result"` on each `Field` does automatic checking comparing with each of the names in `CELEBS`.

I had tried this earlier and was not working which is why I posted on stackoverflow , later realised it wasn't working as `CELEBS` was not loaded yet.
So I had to put a check for it to complete loading before rendering like this:

```
if (CELEBS){
   <div >
     Entire html goes here
   </div >
}
```